# MVC login error - The Remember me? field is required

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

[image]I have a MVC app which has the default login functionality and when I login with out checking the `Remember me` The check box model state gets added an error saying:
 `"The Remember me? field is required."` with `RememberMe` key, its not marked required in Model class. For me Remember me is optional.

So when I check `if(ModelState.IsValid)` before validating the user, the IsValid property is false because of the RememberMe error.

So currently I'm removing this error with  `ModelState["RememberMe"].Errors.Clear();` in Login Action method and check `ModelState.IsValid`.

Is there a better way to avoid this error getting added to the `ModelState`?

I'm using VS 2012 RC

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]    
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl) {
    ModelState["RememberMe"].Errors.Clear();
    if(ModelState.IsValid) {
        if(Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password)) {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
            if(Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                    && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\")) {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }                    
            else {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
        else {
           ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

**Model**

```
public class LoginModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
@{ Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_lightLayout.cshtml"; }
@model MvcFoodService.Models.LoginModel
<div class="accountHeader">
    <h2>
        Log In</h2>
    <p>
        Please enter your username and password. @Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register")
        if you don't have an account.</p>
</div>
@using(Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.DevExpress().Label(settings => {
        settings.Name = "UserNameLabel";
        settings.Text = "User Name";
        settings.AssociatedControlName = "UserName";
    }).GetHtml()

    <div class="form-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.UserName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
    </div>

    @Html.DevExpress().Label(settings => {
        settings.Name = "PasswordLabel";
        settings.Text = "Password";
        settings.AssociatedControlName = "Password";
    }).GetHtml()
    <div class="form-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Password)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
    </div>

    <div class="form-field">
        @Html.DevExpress().CheckBox(settings => {
            settings.Name = "RememberMe";
            settings.Text = "Remember me?";            
        }).GetHtml()
    </div>

    @Html.DevExpress().Button(settings => {
        settings.Name = "Button";
        settings.Text = "Log On";
        settings.UseSubmitBehavior = true;
    }).GetHtml()
}
```

Comment: Could you please `edit your question` and add your model **class definition**. And include the **relevant** portion of your view.

Comment: I'm guessing you are passing back NULL instead of true/false for remember me, maybe something is missing in your view?

Comment: How about you just send back `false`? Having a checkbox be optional doesn't make much sense to me, it's either checked or it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

The `RememberMe` field is a checkbox. That means that it's not supplied in the post if unchecked.

So if you have like this in the action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(string userName, string password, bool rememberMe)
{
}
```

it will fail, since no value is supplied.

You can solve it by modifying the action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(string userName, string password, bool rememberMe = false)
{
}
```

That tells MVC that it's optional.

It can also be solved by including a hidden input in the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="rememberme" value="false" />
<input type="checkbox" name="rememberme" value="true" />
```

That would send two values for rememberme if checked (the last value will be used) or just the hidden value (false) if unchecked.

**Update**

Since you are using a view model you have to make the `RememberMe` field `bool?` or change so there is a hidden input above the checkbox input.

**Update2:**

Just change to this in the view:

```
<div class="form-field">
    @Html.DevExpress().CheckBox(settings => {
        settings.Name = "RememberMe";
        settings.Text = "Remember me?";            
    }).GetHtml()
    <input type="hidden" name="RemberMe" value="false" />
</div>
```

And you're all set.

***Side note***

The code that ASP.NET MVC3:s action helper generates look like this:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Remember me? field is required." id="RememberMe" name="RememberMe" type="checkbox" value="true" />
<input name="RememberMe" type="hidden" value="false" />
```

So DevExpress doesn't follow the behavior of MVC3 (as it should since it's built for ASP.NET MVC)

Comment: That second solution feels wrong, even if it works. Is that how HTTP form values are supposed to work?

Comment: What i meant optional is either the user can check it or dont check it, So if he doesnt check it ModelState.IsValid becomes false as i metioned earlier thanks for all your replies bt i guess u all would have understood my problem better after giving you all the code, Any help is much appreciated

Comment: @NirushanFerdinandChandran: My answer (both solutions) solves the problem with unchecked rememberme.

Comment: Thanks jgauffin bt i use LoginModel in Action Method n the view is different to what you mentioned so can u help me with this?

Comment: Hi  jgauffin, Thanks agn bt the Update 2 doesnt seem like working, appreciate if u can give me a solution thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not psychic. What error do you get? What do the generated HTML look like?

Comment: Check the picture i have added to the original post

Comment: I asked about the generated HTML

Comment: Im Sry im bit new to MVC how to get the generated HTML?

Comment: Right click in Internet Explorer and pick View source. Then find the generated HTML for the remember me parts.

Comment: <!--

var dxo = new ASPxClientCheckBox('RememberMe');
window['RememberMe'] = dxo;
dxo.imageProperties = {'4':['dxWeb_edtCheckBoxChecked_DevEx','dxWeb_edtCheckBoxUnchecked_DevEx'],'8':['dxWeb_edtCheckBoxCheckedDisabled_DevEx','dxWeb_edtCheckBoxUncheckedDisabled_DevEx']};
dxo.icbFocusedStyle = ['dxICBFocused_DevEx',''];
dxo.InlineInitialize();

//-->
</script>
        <input type="hidden" name="RememberMe" value="false" />
    </div>

Comment: you got to ask DevExpress support about that.

Answer (score 1):

The RememberMe field is a devexpress nullable checkbox.
You must set default value

```
@Html.DevExpress().CheckBox(settings => {
        settings.Name = "RememberMe";
        settings.Text = "Remember me?";
        settings.Checked = false;
    }).GetHtml()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a nullable bool.

public bool? RememberMe { get; set; }